# jQuery Differences between .innerWidth and .innerWidth()

Tags: jquery

I am curious why the browser handles `.innerWidth` and `.innerWidth()` differently.  If I call `window.innerWidth()` the console outputs an error saying 'window.innerWidth is not a function.'  When I call `window.innerWidth` it outputs the pixel width like I expect.  But when I call something like `$('random_div').innerWidth` it outputs many lines of code, not what I expect. Though, `$('random_div').innerWidth()` outputs what I expect.

There is no explanation of the differences in the jQuery documentation that I have found. http://api.jquery.com/innerwidth/

https://jsfiddle.net/cyclingpaper/9fmwjLwq/

Thanks for your time.

Comment: A function without `()` is a *function reference*. When the parenthesis are there, it's calling the function.

Comment: If you're using `window.innerWidth` you're just accessing the `innerWidth` property of the window object - it has nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: So window.innerWidth is a javascript function? While the innerWidth() is jQuery?

Comment: `window.innerWidth` isn't a function but a property

Comment: That's not really a dupe imo, here the ambiguity is that jQuery used a window property name to use it as prototype function, it's jQuery after all...  What if someone type `innerWidth` in google?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the one hand there's the [property `innerWidth` of the `window` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerWidth):

```
window.innerWidth;
```

On the other hand jQuery has [a function `.innerWidth()`](http://api.jquery.com/innerwidth/) which can be called on a jQuery object.

And last but not least, you can get a reference to a function by calling it without the braces `()`. That's why calling `.innerWidth` on a jQuery object will return its function body.

Comment: I didn't downvoted but there is no function `$.innerWidth`, i guess you mean `$.fn.innerWidth` the jq prototype one

Comment: @A.Wolff Is there still content wise something wrong with this answer? Or is my wording not technical enough in this case?

Comment: Don't know but looks like someone downvoted all answers here... The question should be downvoted, not really the answers. And you get my vote because imho it is releavnt answer

Comment: It wasn't me that down voted them.. most of them were helpful to my understanding.  Thanks for your response though :D